# How to make raspberry pi into wireless access point (without internet) for local SSH?

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I found many articles about how to setup a raspberry pi into a wireless access point. These articles basically use the pi as a wireless router. They let devices connect to the pi wirelessly and then use the pi's ethernet port to give internet access.

However, I want to do something different. I'm not interested in having internet access on my pi. Instead, I want the pi to be in my backyard and be able to wireless communicate with it from my laptop in my house. My goal is to have the pi act as a wireless access point. My laptop will see the pi's wireless network, connect, and then communicate with the pi using SSH. Again, neither device would have internet access at the time.

Does anybody know how to get this done? I've tried to setting up the access point using a USB wifi in my pi that supports access mode. I could even see and connect to the wireless network on my laptop. But I could never SSH into the pi. Always no connection.

Heeeelllp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an ad-hoc network would work for your application. Check out the thread at the link below.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=15130

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, I'm looking for an ad-hock network with a DHCP server. That way I can communicate with my pi from a distance but without internet access. awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close, just make sure there is no forwarding enabled on Pi. That will mean you dont have internet access when connected over wireless to Pi.

To disable forwarding comment net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf

As for not being able to ssh, probably port 22 is blocked or OpenSSH is not installed.

Hope it helps.